# try to disply data fron json file Nextjs

Tags: json, typescript, next.js, fetch

i wrote this code to get data from json using nextjs
this is the json file:
[json file data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upbyK.png)

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import type { GetStaticProps, NextPage } from "next";
import { randomUUID } from "crypto";

type PageProps = {
  apiData:string
}


const Home: NextPage<PageProps> = ({ apiData }) => {
 
  return <div>
    {JSON.stringify(apiData) }
    {
      apiData.map((i,index)=>{
        i.map((e)=>{
          return (<div key={index}>
            <p>{i.title}</p>
          </div>)
        })
      })
    }
    
 </div>;
};
```

the error is Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Comment: That's because you're typing `apiData` as a string in the `PageProps` type. If it's means to be an array, then type it appropriately. If you need help on how to type it, then please show what the full `apiData` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because apiData is defined as a string (line 6 in your example) and therefore does not contain a method map in its prototype. The method map exists only for arrays.

Try changing the type for your PageProps or parse your JSON-string and make sure that your data is an array.

```
... 

type PageProps = {
  apiData: any[]
}

...
```

Or parse the string to JSON.

```
const Home: NextPage<PageProps> = ({ apiData }) => {

  const parsedData = apiData ? JSON.parse(apiData) : null;

  if (parsedData === null) {
    throw new Error("apiData is not defined.");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {apiData}
      {
        parsedData.map((i, index) => {
          i.map((e) => {
            return (<div key={index}>
              <p>{i.title}</p>
            </div>)
          })
        })
      }

    </div>
  );
};
```